# How cai I send sniffed packet with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, websocket, voip, packet-capture

how can I send sniffed packet with Python?
In particularry, i want to send the SIP/UDP packet that i sniffed with wireshark.[wireshark copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFWqM.png)

Comment: Have you looked at tcpreplay?

Comment: I didn't know it, Thank you!